# How does one cut a circlular quadrant in half vertically?

Tags: geometry

How do I make a cut on a circle quadrant such that the cut is perpendicular to one of the sides, and the area of one section is equal to the area of the other. Here is a picture explaining what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

I want to find *h* such that A1 = A2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\int_0^h \sqrt{1-y^2} dy = \int_h^1 \sqrt{1-y^2} dy$ and solve for $h$.

Comment: Solving for $h$ $\int_0^h \sqrt{1-y^2} dy = \frac{\pi}{8}$ may be easier (since the total area is known)